# Updating a C# desktop application GUI from a dll

Tags: c#, dll, desktop

I am writing a C# desktop application that utilizes a dll (that I wrote) to retrieve data from a database.

The dll has a multitude of functions depending on what data the user wants. I would like to update a label on the UI of my application as the database functions are completed in the dll.

my code is laid out like so:

Application:

```
private void getData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dll.DoDatabaseFunctions();
}
```

DLL:

```
public static DataTable getThisStuff
{
     //connections to SQL DB and runs command
     //HERE is where I would like to send something back to the application to update the label
}

public static DataTable getThatStuff
{
     //connections to SQL DB and runs command
     //HERE is where I would like to send something back to the application to update the label
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the data somewhere in the `DataTable` you return?  Can the form just not get that value out and update the label?

Comment: Use events, check [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, the dll builds a PDF file with the data from the functions. The dll only returns a file path to open the PDF once all the database functions have been completed. I basically want the dll to dynamically keep the application up to date on what its doing.

Comment: In general, it would be a bad idea to couple your nicely independent "DLL" with your UI. If you have to do so, look into Model-View-Presenter and at least code against a View interface, not actual desktop application. That's a side note, before you get deeper into "Updating GUI from DLL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `event` in your dll class that you can subscribe to in your gui.

Declare event in your dll:

```
public event Action DataReady;
```

Raise event in dll when needed:

```
DataReady?.Invoke();
```

or

```
var dataReady = DataReady;
if (dataReady  != null) 
    dataReady();
```

Subscribe to event in gui:

```
dll.DataReady += OnDataReady;
```

Update label in gui when event is raised:

```
public void OnDataReady()
{
     label.Text = "Whatever";
}
```

You can use `Action<T1,..,Tn>` for your event if you need parameters. For example:

```
public event Action<string> DataReady;
DataReady?.Invoke("data");

dll.DataReady += OnDataReady;
public void OnDataReady(string arg1)
{
   label.Text = arg1;
}
```

Lastly, unsubscribe from event when no longer needed:

```
dll.DataReady -= OnDataReady;
```

Comment: No problem! If this worked for you and you believe it can help others, please mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use events. Define an event in your dll class, and you can't really use statics since you need to have an instance (static events are not a good idea).

Something like this:

```
private void getData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var dllInstance = new Dll();
     dll.Updated += dllUpdateReceived;
     dllInstance.DoDatabaseFunctions();
}

private void dllUpdateReceived(object sender, DllUpateEventArgs e)
{
    var updateDescription = e.UpdateDescription;
    // TODO: Update a label with the updates

}
```

And the necessary thingies in the dll project:

```
public class DllUpdateEventArgs: EventArgs {
    public string UpdateDescription { get; set; }
}

public class Dll {
    public event EventHandler<DllUpdateEventArgs> Updated;
    private void OnUpdated(string updateDescription) {
        var updated = Updated;
        if (updated != null) {
            updated(this, new DllUpdateEventArgs { UpdateDescription = updateDescription });
        }
    }

    public void DoDatabaseFunctions() {
        // Do things
        OnUpdated("Step 1 done");
        // Do more things
        OnUpdated("Step 2 done");
        // Do even more things
        OnUpdated("Step 3 done");
    }
}
```